# Topojson 'default' property is Undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, topojson

I've been trying to debug this for the last hour or so to no avail. I'm attempting to use `d3-world-maps`, which has a dependency on `topojson`.

Inside the `d3-world-maps` package lies the issue:

```
var _topojson = require('topojson');
var _topojson2 = _interopRequireDefault(_topojson);
this.countries = _topojson['default'].feature(_assetsTopo_countriesJson2['default'], _assetsTopo_countriesJson2['default'].objects.countries);
```

It seems that `_topojson['default']` is undefined, and I'm not quite familiar with this library or its dependencies enough to figure out why...

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? I've logged the object and I can see that the property `default` is undefined (the object exists) - however I'm not sure why `d3-world-maps` uses it if it doesn't exist... unless I've missed something here.

Edit:

Just looked at the function:

```
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { 
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; 
}
```

What exactly is this doing and why?

Comment: If the issue is inside d3-world-maps source code, you should link the location.

Comment: This is the file (https://github.com/Benjaki2/d3-world-maps/blob/master/src/Map/Map.js), but it looks totally different than the `Maps.js` file `npm` serves. The github is ES6, while the npm package is ES5... Im quite confused, seeing as I followed the instructions on the github directly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be an API change in `topojson`. As you can see [here](https://github.com/Benjaki2/d3-world-maps/blob/master/package.json#L44), `d3-world-maps` uses `*` for the `topojson` version, which means that it will just keep getting the latest version no matter what.

Try editing the package to use a specific, older version of `topojson` and find the version that it's expecting and submit a pull request to the package to fix it!

Comment: I've been trying to no avail. I'll see what I can deduce, but that's a good idea!